# how do I find the ip address of a host on a Windows network?

Tags: windows, ip-address

There is a machine on our network called owner-pc. I want to learn its ip address. I'm not sure which computer it is, and I don't want to trundle to each station to figure it out. When I ping it from the command line on a windows machine, I get something like this:

```
Reply from: fe80::3039:2a21:3f57:f337%1: time<1ms
Reply from: fe80::3039:2a21:3f57:f337%1: time<1ms
Reply from: fe80::3039:2a21:3f57:f337%1: time<1ms
Reply from: fe80::3039:2a21:3f57:f337%1: time<1ms
```

How can I figure this out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `ping -4 owner-pc`

Answer (score 3):

oops should have been an answer

nslookup owner-pc

Answer (score 0):

Thats interesting. I wonder if you're using IPv6. It looks kinda like an IPv6 address.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6

Comment: yes its ipv6 thus ping -4 works or nslookup

Comment: I'm new to IPv6. I was not able to find a description of ping -4 on google. Does ping -4 convert an IPv6 address to IPv4?

Comment: sorry if I seemed scruffy, but no ping -4 just forces ping to use v4 addressing.